# How to make this relation in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, model, database, entity-relationship

[image: A many-to-many toal participation relation (both ways)]

Hello.

As shown in the ER model, I want to create a relation between "Busses" and "Chauffeurs", where every entity in "Chauffeurs" must have at least one relation in "Certified", and every entity in "Busses" must have at least one relation in "Certified".

Though it was pretty easy to design the ER model, I can't seem to find a way of making this relation in PostgreSQL. Anybody got some ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the external predicate for "Certified"? (What does it mean?)

Comment: Hi means that every chauffeur must be certified to drive at least one bus, in order to exist in the chauffeur table. Further, every bus must have at least one chauffeur autherized to drive that bus, in order for the bus to exist in the busses table.

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be database agnostic. If I understand you correctly, you probably want your certified table to look like:

```
CERTIFIED
id
bus_id
chauffer_id
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've been able to find is the notion of a single mandatory field in the parent table to represent the "at least one" and then storing the 2 or more relationships in the intersection table.

### chauffeurs

```
chauffeur_id
chauffer_name
certified_bus_id (not null)
```

### certified

```
chauffer_id
bus_id
```

### busses

```
bus_id
bus_name
certified_chauffer_id (not null)
```

To get a list of all busses where a chauffer is certified becomes

```
select c.chauffer_name, b.bus_name
from chauffeurs c
inner join busses b on (b.bus_id = c.certified_bus_id)
UNION
select c.chauffer_name, b.bus_name
from chauffeurs c
inner join certified ct on (c.chauffeur_id = ct.chauffer_id)
inner join busses b on (ct.bus_id = b.bus_id)
```

The UNION (vs UNION ALL) takes care of deduplication with the values in `certified`.